# What's a reliable method to create a stand alone recovery disk for Lion?

Tags: macos, usb, dvd, recovery

I'm seeing a lot of questions with all sorts of steps to burn a DVD or create a USB disk so you can boot your Mac with Lion if the internal drive is replaced.

Is there a definitive set of steps that is best in terms of support, reliability and cost?

Comment: Today was a good day to ask that question.

Comment: I know :-) jeopardy style

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This might help

http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1433

"The Lion Recovery Disk Assistant lets you create Lion Recovery on an external drive that has all of the same capabilities as the built-in Lion Recovery: reinstall Lion, repair the disk using Disk Utility, restore from a Time Machine backup, or browse the web with Safari."

Comment: In terms of convenience, in case you are offline and don't have Time Machine, nothing beats having a full USB installer too, for which there are many ways to create from the App Store download, on this site. You will need a 4gb Flash disk for that.

Comment: AWESOME on a stick! This news will go over well at the upcoming state fair where everything is batter on a stick.

Answer (score 2):

A 3rd party utility that creates bootable DVD or USB/hard drive installers for OS X 10.6, 10.7, and 10.8 is:  [LionDiskMaker](http://liondiskmaker.com/).

Comment: Very Nice - It turns out this making a DVD/USB drive is harder since Apple is being more free with bundling small installers targeted narrowly for one machine. It makes sense to speed up recovery for people downloading an installer, but if you make a USB - it usually works for the Mac type you downloaded the InstallESD and not all Macs like older retail discs of Mac OS X would do.