# USB Lion Recovery Disk fails to boot

Tags: macos, usb, startup, recovery

Per [What's a reliable method to create a stand alone recovery disk for Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21195/whats-the-best-way-to-create-a-stand-alone-recovery-disk-for-lion), I'm attempting to create a two-partition thumbdrive such that one of the partitions is the Recovery Disk created by [Recovery Disk Assistant](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4848) and the other partition enables me to use the rest of the space for storage. Since I want this storage to be Windows 7/XP-compatible, its format will be MS-DOS(FAT).

So far, my attempts have been thwarted.

When booting my Mac with the thumbdrive inserted, I can select the drive but that only ever results in a [gray screen](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17499/what-should-you-do-if-your-os-x-system-fails-to-boot-being-stuck-at-gray-screen). I have enabled FileVault 2 on this machine, if that matters.

What magic do I need to get a working external Recovery Disk on my thumbdrive?

Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21303/two-partition-thumbdrive-unrecognized-under-boot-camp-windows-7

Answer (score 1):

I have done this using the raw InstallESD.dmg image from the Mac App Store Lion installer (NOT the Recovery Disk Assistant) using the following steps:

- Drag the InstallESD.dmg image to Disk Utility so that it appears on the side bar
- Select your USB drive and partition the drive in to 2 or more GUID partitions
- Once partitioning is complete, select the Restore tab
- Drag that InstallESD.dmg image from the side bar to the source field
- Drag the first partition from the USB drive on the side bar to the target field
- Begin the restore process

Once finished you can leave things as they are or re-format the other partition as ExFAT or MS-DOS. However you should be aware the USB drive is GUID partitioned so only Windows 7 is likely to read it properly (I've never tried a GUID partioned USB drive on an XP system). You cannot use standard MBR partitions for the Lion Recovery Partition.