# Clean install of Mountain Lion on MBP early 2011 failed

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, install, usb, recovery

I want to install a fresh version of mountain lion via usb stick on my macbookpro (early 2011) + new Samsung 840 SSD. (NVRAM cleared, HDD Empty)

1.) I created a usb installer as described here: http://macs.about.com/od/macoperatingsystems/ss/Create-Bootable-Copies-Of-The-Os-X-Mountain-Lion-Installer_4.htm
2.) Rebooted, Pressed ALT/Option
3.) selected the USB Stick as Boot medium
-> After a little while a forbidden icon is displayed

The internet recovery works fine, but installs 10.7.5 .. i want 10.8.2.

What is the problem here? How to fix it. I dont want to install 10.7 and update to 10.8.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to create a stand alone recovery disk for Lion?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21195/whats-the-best-way-to-create-a-stand-alone-recovery-disk-for-lion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue using the [Lion DiskMaker](http://liondiskmaker.com/)